# Is there a simple way to turn the byte array from the camera's onPreviewFrame into a picture in android?

Tags: android, image, camera, preview

I ask if there is a simple way because there is a google issue report saying that using decodeByteArray isn't possible. But that report originated in 2008 and I was hoping there was a solution not posted on there. The method listed on the issue report was to decode the format yourself, but I'd prefer to not have to put that in and slow down the program. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a BufferedImage the following way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0. data.length);
```

data is the byte array.

Comment: Um are you sure that works in Android? I can't find any reference material for BufferedImage or ImageIO. Its listed in the Java language reference but not Android's

Comment: THats what I originally thought the answer was, but it gives me a null bitmap back.

Comment: The reason why you're having a null bitmap is because the byte array is in NV21 format check @James Burnstone answer below.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming your byte array is from the camera preview? If so you have to decode it but with 2.2 it's quite easy now.

Create a YUV image from the byte array as the data will only be in `ImageFormat.NV21( int code 17)`

```
img = new YuvImage(imgData, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
```

Create a rectangle the same size as the image.

Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and pass this, the rectangle and the compression value to `compressToJpeg()`.

Then you can use

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outputStream.toByteArry(),0,outputStream.size());
```

I use this for every frame in the callback and it works fine. Hope this helps.