# How To Parse Image Byte[] Array

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, byte

My Android camera is passing through an entire image into onPreviewFrame, but I only want the bytes that correspond to a pixel range.
For instance an image that is 480x640 in pixels is passed through. I want a new byte[] Array with the pixels in the the range of Rect(100,100,200,200)

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
    // arg0 = 460,800 BYTES
    // the camera's resolution is at 640 x 480
    // arg0 format is NV21
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656350/android-camera-how-can-i-take-a-specific-rectangle-from-the-byte-array.  The word you are looking for is "cropping."

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747295/crop-particular-part-of-image-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try using  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

and the method newInstance(InputStream stream, boolean isShareable) of the BitmapRegionDecoder class.And next You can use

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = newInstance(stream,false)
Bitmap region = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(x, y, x1, y1), null);
```

Comment: I tried using this method but it only supports JPEG & PNG picture formats and my android camera doesn't support either. But thanks anyways!